# Insignificant “time variable” in GLM?

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance, generalized-linear-model, sas

I'm used to GLM modelling with a time variable, eg. Month or Year, main reason being it is often used as a proxy for an immeasurable variable, or simply data you can not easily obtain, econometrically speaking.

I now have the case where all the given time variables are statistically insignificant, (really high p-values). Would it be good practice to keep the insignificant time variable in the model to 'capture' the immeasurable annual effects, or simply to remove the variable and argue that it has a negligible effect?

Comment: If you have substantive grounds for including Month and Year in the model, you should keep them in the model regardless of the inisignificant p-values. Recall that, If you have a small number of observations in your model, your p-values may come out insignificant as a consequence of the small sample size.